# Understanding Scale in Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to understand the scale parameter in earth engine better. My goal is to calculate monthly sums of precipitation across a geometry. Here is the python pseudo code:

```
area = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-120.29277343749999, 37.319672371647655],
          [-118.51298828124999, 35.13985393638227],
          [-117.10673828124999, 35.552070101618895],
          [-118.46904296874999, 37.73787899128162]]])

col = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81m')
t = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2014,2014,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4,4,'month'))
    .filterBounds(area).select("ppt")

result = t.getRegion(area, scale).getInfo()
```

However this gives very different sums depending on the scale parameter value that is supplied. Here is a plot for the image sum as a function of scale parameter:

[image: p vs scale]

Is the best practice to reduce as sum before calling `getRegion` and `getInfo`? I have read the documentation on scale in earth engine, and the native resolution suggested by the dataset is 2.5 arc minutes or approximately 4.5 km. I am curious what the best practices are for supplying a scale parameter, especially when working with multiple data sources over the same area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing working code it's hard to say for sure, but here's a guess.  (And I presume `getRegion()` is not really what you want or what you're using).  In the dataset you describe, precipitation is in mm.  When you aggregate pixels in Earth Engine, say with something like `image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry, scale)`, the input is resampled as necessary to `scale`, then all the pixels are summed.  Doing that with mm doesn't make sense since you need to scale precipitation in mm by `ee.Image.pixelArea()` (which is in square meters) converted to square mm.  It's the scaling step which I think you're missing.